# how to update d3 graph in react using redux actions?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to store data from tooltip using redux action called in mouse events (mouseenter, mouseleave).

The problem:  When mouse cursor is on element (g element) I expected only `mouseenter` event but `mouseleave` is also triggered. This cause updating redux store and re-rendering react component in a loop.

I have an svg element and then I append g element, which is wrapper for circle and text. I added event listeners on g element.

Here is my code:

```
const SomeReactComponent =() => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const createChart = () => {

    const svg = d3
      .select(svgNode)
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .style('border', '2px solid black')
      .append('g')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        `translate(${width / 2 + margin.left / 2},${height / 2 + margin.top})`
      );

const Tooltip = d3
        .select('.polar-scatter-chart')
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'tooltip');

const wrapper = svg
      .selectAll('Points')
      .data(newData)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .on('mouseenter', ({ id, name, themeName }) => {
        Tooltip.html(name)
          .style('visibility', 'visible')
          .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY - 350}px`)
          .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX}px`);
          dispatch(handleTooltip({ id, themeName }));
        }
      })
      .on('mouseleave', () => {
        Tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
          dispatch(handleTooltip({ id: '', themeName: '' }));
      });
    wrapper
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'point')
      .attr('transform', (d, i) => {})
      .attr('r',7)

    wrapper
      .append('text')
      .attr('transform', (d) => {})
      .text((d) => some_text);
  };
 }

 createChart();

  return (
    <div className="polar-scatter-chart">
      <svg ref={svgRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

How Can I properly update d3 graph using redux actions ?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

You are calling createChart on every render, creating a whole new set of elements that are probably on  top of the elements that are already existing.
So every time, you "leave" the old element because you "enter" the one that is drawn on top.

If you want to do it that way, you should wrap `createChart` in a `useEffect` call and only execute it once.

But the better idea would be to go with a D3 library for react.